# Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll while the exe seems to work fine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

### Problem:

When starting C# application in visual studio, I have this error “exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll” However, when I launch the application, it is working fine and doesn't crash.

### Questions:

**- Can I ignore it?**

It doesn’t seem to impact anything (the exe program works fine), does it mean I can ignore the error ? (This library is not used in anywhere important, so I can ignore the exception related to loading the library?)

**- How to get rid of it? I am not even sure why would this error occur:**

As much as I want to get rid of the error, I am also not sure how to. I didn’t make any change to the mscorlib reference in csproj, I have only upgraded the dot net framework from 4.5.2 to 4.8, I am not sure if this will somehow cause this exception?

**- Is my understanding of why this exception is shown correct?:**

As a beginner, I know that sometimes when a c# application throws an exception during execution, then there’ll be a message pop-up directly.
However, for this exception that just shows up in terminal, it seems to be because it’s related to loading library, and it wouldn’t crash the program. Is my understanding correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "running C# application" do you mean from Visual Studio? You need to more specific, as the question stands it makes little sense.

Comment: It sound like a "Silent Exception"(you may want to look that up) while you are debugging. In that case that would be OK. But can't put actual confidence behind it without seeing it myself.

Comment: If your program can run successfully according to your expectations, then this issue can be ignored, but if you want to figure out this issue, you can refer to the following suggestions:
 
Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find missing files. Of course, there will be three situations.
 
1) The file does not exist.
2) Path error.
3) The security permissions of the folder are high, resulting in inaccessibility.
 
Then you can further improve your program according to the above situation.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes you can ignore it until it causes undefined behaviour or errors that crash/pause the program
2. you can supress it but i don't think that's a good idea
3. i don't think the error is related to the loading library, but rather that you are trying to read a file that doesn't exist, or something of the like.
   it would be helpful if you could show some code. This would give me more of an idea as to why the error is occuring. by the way which script is this error originating from?